# Any tool to view .mvt files content in human readable form

Tags: vector-tiles

I have tried with [protobufeditor](http://protobufeditor.sourceforge.net/) but didn't succeed to open it. I need something similar to check for errors in existing files, and binary data is too hard to read when file is large. I have downloaded [vector_tile.proto](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/blob/master/2.1/vector_tile.proto) file and compiled it with google libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works but **protobufedior** does not ship **protoc.exe** in installation, so you need to have **protoc.exe** on your PATH.